# Prove that$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-2^{n}}$ converges to an irrational limit.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Prove that$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-2^{n}}$ converges to an irrational limit.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: You are asking different thing in the post from the title.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now.

Comment: Consider the development of the limit in base $2$. Is it periodic?

Comment: showing it is even transcendental should not be too hard, given that it has so good approximations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary representation $0.01010001\cdots$ doesn't terminate or repeat.